# Using environment variables with Python in Powerbi

Tags: python, powerbi, environment-variables

I have a script that connects to a third party API that uses a public and secret key. The connection is written in python and works on PowerBI desktop and also on the web app in production.

However the keys are hard coded into the script and this doesn't feel like best practice. Is there a way to use Environment Variables in PowerBI so I can remove the keys from the script?

Answer (score 2):

I was just working on this today! I was able to store my credentials as environment variables on my computer and then call them in my python script using `os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")` etc.

I did have to restart my PowerBI Desktop after saving them to my computer.

Additional information -
os is a [python library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) to interface with your local machine. `os.getenv` [accesses the environment variables](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-getenv-method/) that you have stored on your system. Windows users can create env vars [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/machine-learning/oml4r/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html) and mac users typically set them via terminal [like this](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/set-environment-variable-mac)

Comment: I suggest that you explain what `os.getenv` does and how you create the environment variables

Comment: `os` is a [python library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) to interface with your local machine. `os.getenv` [accesses the environment variables](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-getenv-method/) that you have stored on your system. Windows users can create env vars [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/machine-learning/oml4r/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html) and mac users typically set them via terminal [like this](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/set-environment-variable-mac)

Comment: I do agree that hard coding the credentials into your script is not good from a security best practice perspective. And agree that saving these as environment variables on your machine can eliminate that security issue.

Comment: Can you please include those comments in your answer? They're really good additions.

Comment: Of course! I've made the update